# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,060.00'- astype(float)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

As you can see I am trying to convert string to float, I came across this code in github and I wanted to see how well it worked with my own data. But I am having a problem in this code, whenever i run it, returns ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,060.00'- astype(float). Is something wrong with this code?

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

minmax = MinMaxScaler().fit(df.iloc[:, 4:5].astype('float32'))

df_log = minmax.transform(df.iloc[:, 4:5].replace.astype('float32')) 

df_log = pd.DataFrame(df_log)

df_log.head()
```

[this is the data i am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/923To.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"1,060.00" can not be converted to float because of the comma in there. Try replacing all commas in your specific column with "" (empty string) using [this function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) before casting to float.